# Is "goon" really modern?

Tags: meaning

Since "gun" in Norse German makes "Gunther" mean "warrior, then could "gaunre," (which means "steal" in Dutch Mennonite Nether Saxon -- Low German) be the origin of "gun" heard in English "goon"?  After all, "theft" has always been a motive for starting a war, and warfare demands brutal (goonish) behaviour.  (I am aware "goon" is considered modern, but, in view of the foregoing, am beginning to suspect otherwise.) Note: "gaunre" does not mean "stealing" in the usual sense.  Its normally employed in the trivial sense: as in, "to hook an apple (gaunah een aupel) while walking past an orchard", or in the socially acceptable sense, like victors unashamedly boasting about looting the vanquished.  Thus, could English "gain" trace its root to "gaunre" as well, or am I merely dabbling in dangerous derivations and chance coincidences?

Comment: perhaps it comes from "lagoon" under the assumption that it is French for "the goon".  Do you have any instance of someone using goon or a soundalike as you posit?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Is this idle speculation, or have you done research into the matter? I ask because you do not make any mention of the traditional etymology (see [Etymonline](http://etymonline.com/index.php?search=goon) and [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/goon) to start), which links it to *gooney* and *gony*.

Answer (score 2):

I have tried several dictionaries, and they all seem to agree that the modern word comes from 'gony' (= simpleton), first recorded in about 1580.

Comment: Please provide  links and sources of your findings.